# Question about Orlicz space.

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to extend Kolmogorov theorem to the Orlicz space. But I am facing some difficulties while calculating the norm.

I have tried to proof the extended version with a similar proof. So in the Orlicz space, we have to show that $||f-Pf||_{\Phi}<\epsilon$ which means the Orlicz norm should be less than $\epsilon.$ This is my calculation please suggest to me what to do after this

$$||f-Pf||_{\Phi} =  \inf\left\{\beta>0 : \int_{\mathbb R^n}\Phi(\frac{|f(x)-Pf(x)|}{\beta})\leq 1\right\}$$
Our goal is find such $\beta>0$ such that  $\int_{\mathbb R^n}\Phi(\frac{|f(x)-Pf(x)|}{\beta})\leq 1.$
Let us assume $\int_{\mathbb R^n}\Phi(\frac{|f(x)-Pf(x)|}{\beta})\leq 1$ which implies that
$$\int_{\mathbb R^n}\Phi(\frac{|f(x)-\frac{1}{|Q_i|}\int_{Q_i}f(z)dz|}{\beta})\leq 1$$
which implies that
$$\int_{\mathbb R^n}\Phi \left(\frac{\frac{1}{|Q_i|}\int_{Q_i}(|f(x)-f(z)|)dz}{\beta}\right)dx\leq 1$$

My intuition is saying that somehow we need to modify the condition (iii) of the original theorem to get such $\beta$ but I am stuck here. Any help or hint will be great for me. Thanks.

Comment: To editors: why remove the reference to the paper?

Comment: Why edit the question in a way that it does not resemble original one? And even it no longer is a question?

Answer (score 1):

The version of Theorem 5 for Orlicz space reads as follows. Denote by $\mathbb L_\Phi$ the space of functions $f$ for which the norm $\lVert f\rVert_\Phi$ is finite. A function $\Phi$ satisfies the $\Delta_2$ condition if there exists a constant $C$ such that for each $t\geqslant 0$, $\Phi(2t)\leq C\Phi(t)$. Define also
$$
\widetilde{\Phi}(t):=\sup \{ts-\Phi(s),s\geqslant 0\}.
$$

> **Theorem** Let $\Phi$ be a Young function such that $\Phi$ and $\widetilde{\Phi}$ satisfy the $\Delta_2$ condition. A subset $\mathcal F$ of $\mathbb L_\Phi$ is totally bounded if and only if the following conditions are satisfied:
> (i) $\mathcal F$ is bounded,
> (ii) $\lim_{R\to\infty}\sup_{f\in\mathcal F}\lVert f(\cdot)\mathbf{1}_{\lvert\cdot\rvert >R}\rVert_{\Phi}=0 $
> (iii) $\lim_{\rho\to\infty}\sup_{y:\lvert y\rvert<\rho}\lVert f(\cdot +y)-f(\cdot)\rVert_{\Phi}=0$.

The assumption on $\Phi$ and $\widetilde{\Phi}$ is made in order to have the density of smooth functions with compact support in $\mathbb L_\Phi$ (see Corollary 3.1 [in these notes](https://www.jams.jp/scm/contents/Vol-10-1/10-6.pdf)), which is needed in order to check that a finite set satisfies (iii), and makes the life easier for (ii).

With this in mind, one can see that a finite set satisfies (i), (ii) and (iii) hence these conditions are necessary.

For sufficiency, we will mimic the proof in the link mentioned in the opening post. Let $\mathcal F\subset\mathbb L_\Phi$ be a set satisfying conditions (i), (ii) and (iii). Fix a positive $\varepsilon$ and choose $R$ and $\rho$   such that
$\sup_{f\in\mathcal F}\lVert f(\cdot)\mathbf{1}_{\lvert\cdot\rvert >R}\rVert_{\Phi}<\varepsilon$ and
$\sup_{y:\lvert y\rvert<\rho}\lVert f(\cdot +y)-f(\cdot)\rVert_{\Phi}<\varepsilon$.

Let $Q$ be an open cube which is contained in the open ball centered at the origin with radius $\rho/2$. Pick $Q_1,\dots, Q_N$ non-overlaping translated of $Q$ (that is, $Q_i=y_i+Q$) such that the closure of $\bigcup_{i=1}^NQ_i$ contains the balls centered at the origin with radius $R$. Define
$$
Pf(x)=\sum_{i=1}^N\frac  1{\lvert Q_i\rvert}\int_{Q_i}f(z)dz\mathbf{1}_{Q_i}(x).
$$
Note that the following equality holds almost everywhere

$$
f(x)-Pf(x)=f(x)\mathbf{1}_{x\notin \bigcup_{i=1}^NQ_i}
+\sum_{i=1}^N\mathbf{1}_{Q_i}(x)\left(f(x)-\frac  1{\lvert Q_i\rvert}\int_{Q_i}f(z)dz\right).
$$
and that
$$
\left\lVert f(\cdot)\mathbf{1}_{\cdot\notin \bigcup_{i=1}^NQ_i} \right\rVert_{\Phi}\leqslant \left\lVert f(\cdot)\mathbf{1}_{\lvert \cdot\rvert >R } \right\rVert_{\Phi}<\varepsilon.
$$
Moreover, for each positive $\lambda$,
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^n}\Phi\left(\frac 1{\lambda}\left\lvert\sum_{i=1}^N\mathbf{1}_{Q_i}(x)\left(f(x)-\frac  1{\lvert Q_i\rvert}\int_{Q_i}f(z)dz\right)\right\vert\right)dx\\=\sum_{i=1}^N\int_{Q_i}\Phi\left(\frac 1{\lambda}\left\lvert \frac  1{\lvert Q_i\rvert}\int_{Q_i}\left(f(x)-f(z)\right)dz\right\rvert\right)dx\mbox{ non overlapping} \\
=\sum_{i=1}^N\int_{Q_i}\Phi\left(\frac 1{\lambda}\left\lvert \frac  1{\lvert Q_i\rvert}\int_{Q_i-x}\left(f(x)-f(x+y)\right)dy\right\rvert\right)dx \mbox{ substitution }z=x+y\\
\leqslant \sum_{i=1}^N\int_{Q_i} \frac  1{\lvert Q_i\rvert}\int_{Q_i-x}\Phi\left(\frac 1{\lambda} \left\vert f(x)-f(x+y)\right\rvert  \right)dy dx \quad \mbox{ Jensen's inequality}\\
\leqslant \sum_{i=1}^N\int_{Q_i} \frac  1{\lvert Q_i\rvert}\int_{2Q}\Phi\left(\frac 1{\lambda} \left\vert f(x)-f(x+y)\right\rvert   \right)dy dx\\
\leqslant  \int_{2Q} \frac  1{\lvert Q\rvert}\int_{\mathbb R}\Phi\left(\frac 1{\lambda} \left\vert f(x)-f(x+y)\right\rvert \right)dx dy. 
$$
Choosing now $\lambda$ such that $\int_{\mathbb R}\Phi\left(\frac 1{\lambda} \left\vert f(x)-f(x+y)\right\rvert \right)dx<\varepsilon$ for each $y\in Q$, which is possible by (iii) and the $\Delta_2$ condition.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer can you clear what condition we should assume? I have tried taking the 3rd condition similar as in the $L^p$ case but failed in it. Do you have any suggestion for this?

Comment: @Andyale Hello, you are welcome. I will write a more expanded version of this answer in the next days. If I forget, please ping me.

Comment: hello sir can you please provide me the expanded version, it will help me to understand it more clearly.

Comment: hey ! If you get time please explain me the answer, Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I do not know whether you get notified in case of an edit. Here is a more expanded version.

Comment: There is one issue I have found is that we have to show the norm $||f-Pf||_{\Phi}\leq \epsilon $(say) but in the case of orlicz space the norm is the infimum of $\lambda$ such that $\int_{\mathbb{R^n}}\Phi(./\lambda)d\mu\leq 1$, but you are calculating $\lambda$ without the less than equal 1 condition.